# Expanding a shortened url to its original full length url in java

Tags: java, url, urlconnection

I'm attempting to take a shortened url and expand it out to its original full length url in a string format in java. I've been able to track down a tutorial online, however I'm unable to get this to actually get me the full url. Has anyone done this before or know how to do this? Any help is huge, thanks

```
URLConnection conn = null;
try {
    URL inputURL = new URL("http://bit.ly/9mglq8");
    conn = inputURL.openConnection();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

} catch (IOException ioe) {

}
String realU = conn.toString();
Toast.makeText(ImagetestActivity.this, realU,
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: What tutorial? How about providing a link to it?

Answer (score 7):

```
System.out.println("Short URL: "+ shortURL);
                urlConn =  connectURL(shortURL);
                urlConn.getHeaderFields();
                System.out.println("Original URL: "+ urlConn.getURL());

/* connectURL - This function will take a valid url and return a 
URL object representing the url address. */
URLConnection connectURL(String strURL) {
        URLConnection conn =null;
 try {
     URL inputURL = new URL(strURL);
     conn = inputURL.openConnection();
            int test = 0;

 }catch(MalformedURLException e) {
     System.out.println("Please input a valid URL");
 }catch(IOException ioe) {
     System.out.println("Can not connect to the URL");
 }
 return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably want to going to use the [expand lookup](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_expand) in the official bit.ly API, or the [getHeaderField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29) method of URLConnection to grab the `Location` header.

I've never done either of these, and I'm assuming there wouldn't be any problems with the latter, but I suppose the official method is probably the way to go to guarantee you're getting what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void getURL(String bitly) throws SQLException {   
        
        URLConnection conn = null;
        String bitlyLink = null;
        try {
            URL inputURL = new URL(bitlyLink);
            conn = inputURL.openConnection();
            conn.getHeaderFields();
            System.out.println("Original URL: "+ conn.getURL());

        } catch(Exception e) { 
          System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the bit.ly spec:

How does bitly work?
bitly works by issuing a "301 redirect": a technique for making a webpage available under many URLs. When you shorten a link with bitly, you are redirecting a click from bitly to the destination URL. A 301 redirect is the most efficient and search engine-friendly method for webpage redirection, and is what bitly uses. Because bitly doesn’t re-use or modify links, we consider our redirects to be permanent.

What this means is that you have to look at the "Location" Header to figure out where to redirect to when you get a 301 response code.  Here's a sample 301 response:

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/index.asp